# How to setup/deploy web functionality tests (watir/selenium)

Tags: selenium, implementation, watir

I've been looking into this for a few days now, and I'm not getting a good picture of how this is supposed to work. I've been tasked with exploring/getting the ball rolling on some automated, front end functionality testing for my company's web apps.

So far I'm looking at selenium or watir with web-driver, and hopefully some kind of headless browser option.

The idea is to have these scripts reside on the development server (managed by Git) where any one can invoke them, and they will be automatically invoked for new release merges, but also, they need to be accessible to individual developers to run on an actual browser (I assume this has to be local), in addition to a headless browser, for debugging and further test development.

I've seen a few things about CI (continuous integration), but to honest, I'm fairly overwhelmed right now. If anyone could provide an example structure of how I could set this up, or at least what I would need, I would be most grateful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The quick end of it, from my experience, using Selenium (WebDriver) and Python is quick and easy. I use PyTest to execute the tests. The CI is done by a Jenkins server. PyTest for the reports (read by Jenkins using the .xml reporting). You can record simple tests using the FireFox plugin (Selenium) and export them as a Python file for use with WebDriver.

FireFox (Selenium): https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/selenium-expert-selenium-ide/
Selenium and Python: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Pytest: http://pytest.org/latest/

Developers also like this option as they can run them from command line (as Jenkins does). Easier to maintain, execute and update.

Comment: I guess I'm more confused than I initially thought. If you're using PyTest to run scripts, what is the purpose of selenium? I was under the impression that selenium provided everything I needed to write and execute tests. The more I look around, I realize I no one seems to use JUST selenium, and I really have no idea what all this other stuff is used for.

Comment: Selenium is the library that actually executes the tests. Py.test integrates test methodologies. I use it (partly) like this: `dave$ py.test --verbose -k test_` The command line arguments, `--verbose` gives a terminal display of the tests running. `-k test_` tells py.test to only recognize def with the string test in it. There are several reporting tools to use with py.test as well. `--cov` and `--junitxml` are a few I like.

Answer (score 0):

I gave a few talks about our setup and documented them on my blog. For example:

- http://filipin.eu/how-mediawiki-software-that-runs-wikipedia-is-tested/
- http://filipin.eu/selenium-conference-2013/
- http://filipin.eu/browser-automation-workshop/